# Why does xvid encoding lag/lock up windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, video, encoding, lag, xvid

It seems to encode just fine.

If you look at the mouse cursor you'll see firefox locks up once i click it. Calculator seems fine but when i try to move it, it locks up. The resource monitor and task manager are up so you can see if the CPU is being used up. It isnt as you can see <30% was used.

-edit- i mentioned in a comment -> If you look at the video it isnt logical for calc to lock up when trying to movie it. Especially not after you can see the button lights glow. Its something about explorer (it seems)

Comment: caution: NSFW popups @sendspace

Comment: oops. Sorry. I didnt realize. I have adblocks and when i was on the site before adblock it was always SFW and never a pop up

Comment: You might consider posting your PC specs.

Comment: Link removed due to no longer being valid.

Answer (score 0):

I can already see in the Resource Monitor that the CPU Maximum Frequency (blue line in CPU graph) is not at 100%.

Windows underclocks (basically reduces your CPU clock speed) when it is idling or not doing anything that is CPU intensive. 
The PC then needs to supply the CPU with a smaller voltage,
and the CPU usage is a percentage of the maximum clock frequency.

Yours seems to be at about 80%, so your CPU speed is already reduced to 80% of its capacity.

I can also see high peaks in disk I/O.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I would guess that you're using a portable computer while not connected to electricity. Windows then reduces performance in order to save on power, so anything you do is slowed down to start with. Windows 7 is especially designed to conserve power and prolong battery life.

I would suggest to connect the computer to the power mains, and/or change the power option to High performance. See if this article helps:
[How to Manage Windows 7 Power Settings](http://blog.enterpriseitplanet.com/green/blog/2009/01/how-to-manage-windows-7-power-settings.html)

You also need to accept that video-encoding is resource-intensive, as is Firefox.

Comment: It is a laptop, but it also is plugged in. I found the max processor state in advance options and both plug and unplug set it to 100% (unplugged 100% surprises me)

Comment: @acidzombie24: It might be that the laptop simply isn't fast enough to do too many things at once. It might help to know which model it is, and whether the CPU is multi-core or at least multi-thread. Have you checked the power settings?

Comment: Using this CPU (i def needed 2 cores) Intel® Pentium® Dual Core™ T4400 and these links are relevant http://configure.us.dell.com/dellstore/config.aspx?oc=dncwzs1&c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&kc=laptop-inspiron-1545 http://www.dell.com/us/en/home/notebooks/laptop-inspiron-1545/pd.aspx?refid=laptop-inspiron-1545&cs=19&s=dhs (click on tech specs)

Comment: Yes i checked it. The CPU state is set to max @ 100. If you look at the video it isnt logical for calc to lock up when trying to movie it. Especially not after you can see the button lights glow. Its something about explorer (it seems)

Answer (score 0):

Simply try to use a different encoder application like AviDemux, mencoder, ffmpeg, whatever fits your need.

Comment: well, its encoding my screen realtime. I would have to encode it differently first and right now the issue with other encoders (ATM with the defaults except xvid) they all dont allow me to use a low even quality to not run out of space in a few (like 10) 2hour session

Comment: what do you mean? So you RECORD your screen? Lol you didnt mention that at ALL. You should use an app which records in raw avi first.

Comment: oops i guess you couldnt tell. raw avi, even worse. It be great if i could try piping it to ffmpeg while screen recording (i want to do a 3 hour job then check out where i waste time during). raw avi should definitely kill my HDD space. Maybe i should just move the video everytime i am finished one.

Comment: Or use an external hdd. But these are the options, nothing else.